# How to activate virtualenv using python subprocess module?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to invoke a shell script using python's subprocess module.
The shell script activates a virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper and in turn invokes a python script.
The last invoked python script needs libraries installed in virtualenv and it is crashing.

> tried activating virtualenv again in python script but of no use

Parent Python code-

```
command = "/home/arman/analysis_server/new_analysis/run"

output = subprocess.Popen([command], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

/run script -

```
#!/bin/bash

export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

workon analytics

python /home/arman/analysis_server/new_analysis/AnalysisWrapper.py
```

AnalysisWrapper.py -

```
cmd = "python /home/arman/analysis_server/new_analysis/DataHandlerWrapper.py " + instrument + " &"

subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', stdout=out, stderr=out)
```

The **DataHandlerWrapper.py** script needs virtualenv but it is crashing

Comment: do you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: can't you convert `AnalysisWrapper.py` to bash script with `python /home/arman/analysis_server/new_analysis/DataHandlerWrapper.py instrument &` ? Or even with code which activates virtualenv for `DataHandlerWrapper.py`.

Comment: No actually there are some checks and logic to kill stale DataHandlerWrapper process in AnalysisWrapper.py , after this it invokes DataHandlerWrapper with given arguments

Comment: Similar... Probably a duplicate of

Comment: and no error messages, just I can't see the DataHandlerWrapper process running after this.
Also this works if call it directly from shell like ./run but not working when called from python code

Answer (score 3):

I think your issue is that Popen spawns a subshell, so you activating the virtualenv in one subprocess and trying to use it in another is never going to work.

If there's nothing happening in between you could perhaps try chaining your commands into the same process:

```
command = "/home/arman/analysis_server/new_analysis/run && python /home/arman/analysis_server/new_analysis/DataHandlerWrapper.py " + instrument + " &"
```

Comment: Side note: If you're not tied to using virtualenv for this case, you may also want to take a look at pipx, which might be of some help: https://pipxproject.github.io/pipx/